# Use case_when to add a new column in R

Tags: r, case

I have two `DataFrame` a, b that share a common column wih same variables. I wand to add the column **fa** from the **b** to the dataframe **a** using the `case_when` statement. Sofar what I achieved:

'''

```
a = data.frame(name = c("a","c","d"))
b = data.frame(device = c("a","c","d"), fa = c(1:3))

for ( i in 1:length(b$device)){
    a1 <- a  %>% 
    mutate( fa = case_when(
            name == b$device[i] ~b$fa[i]
                          )
          )
}
```

*Output*

```
name    fa
<chr>   <int>
a   NA
c   NA
d   3
```

I know where the problem lies, but I was not able to fix it. I would really appreciate any advice:

*Expected output:*

```
name    fa
<chr>   <int>
a   1
c   2
d   3
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand correctly, but I think, what you actually want is a `left_join`.

```
left_join(x = a
          , y = b
          , by = c("name" = "device"))
```

There is no need for a for loop, because `dplyr` works row-wise per default.

```
a %>%  mutate(fa = ifelse((b$device)==name,b$fa,NA))
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response, your second approach seems  more plausible. Unfortunately, it did not work well.  As the two dframes do not have same dimentions , I had an error like this "i longer object length is not a multiple of
  shorter object length ".  The actual case is that the df _a_ is huge, while df _b_ is small with 18 variable in  the column **fa**. So the idea is to use the case_when to add a new column to the df _a_ with variables from the df **b$fa** if name and device is identical. I hope I made it bit clear.

Comment: But then the join does even make more sense.

Comment: Wow, that works perfectly, Some times, it helps one thinks things simpler. thank you.